# JPA: Deleting detached instance

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, hibernate-annotations

I get resultList from typedQuery object.
I take first object from that list.

eg. `LoginAttempt loginAttempt = loginAttempts.get(0);`

When, I update this object and call `entityManager.merge(loginAttempt);` it is updated successfully.

But when I am going to delete this object it gives me exception ie. `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Removing a detached instance.`

Any suggestion. Thanks :)

Actually, I want to remove only. I just mention merge because, I am get confused that merge is working but remove is not working...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Merge is actually working because it's purpose is to transit from detached to managed state. Remove, on the other hand, can work only on managed entities.

If you have a managed entity, you can invoke `em.remove(-)` on it.
If you have a detached entity, you should invoke `Object managed = em.merge(detached)` and then `em.remove(managed)`. You must do this within the same transaction boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

A [quick search reveals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7448392/how-do-i-make-my-entity-object-managed-so-i-can-remove-it) that you need to do this in the same transaction. You cannot merge and then delete. You need to do it in the same transaction, or separate them in two transactions

Comment: Actually, I want to remove only. I just mention merge because, I am get confused that merge is working but remove is not working...